# Cucumber tests strange error at end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have a strange error when running a cucumber test. All tests run fine, but there is this error at the end:

```
→ bundle exec rake cucumber
/Users/rudolf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...

(All tests run properly at this point)

27 scenarios (27 passed)
245 steps (245 passed)
0m27.778s
/Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1037:in `block in process_args': invalid option: --profile (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1016:in `new'
    from /Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1016:in `process_args'
    from /Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1066:in `_run'
    from /Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1059:in `run'
    from /Users/rudolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:795:in `block in autorun'
```

I am using Ruby 2 with Rails 4, this is the test part in my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'nokogiri'
end
```

I also run these tests on Semaphore (https://semaphoreapp.com), it happens there too.

Edit: `cucumber.yml`:

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

Comment: What does your `cucumber.yml` look like?

Comment: Also update the `minitest`. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cukes/wACWHhHvvmE/pu87az2FOBEJ

Comment: I don't have a cucumber.yml anywhere, should there be one by default? I use version 4.7.5 according to `bundle install`: `Using minitest (4.7.5)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just missed it. I updated the post with the `cucumber.yml`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update minitest to latest and try again?

Comment: No, when I request 5.0.7 in my Gemfile I get an error stating that `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "minitest":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      minitest (~> 4.2) ruby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with a massive amount of googling and trying: When I run

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

or only

```
cucumber
```

(without the `rake`) it works fine. This doesn't fix the problem really, but it at least it works now.